# LAMP: Custom 500 error page - is it actually possible?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, 500-error

As the Question title suggests,
I want to setup a custom 500 error.
In fact, I want to use a .php file for the error, and ideally send a 503 response (SE Reasons).

The problem is that the only way I know to generate a 500 response is via .htaccess, and it shows the server's built-in/default 500 error page.
(I am assuming this, since the error occurs in .htaccess; it isn't processed and can't show the custom one.)

So my questions are:
1) Is it actually possible to generate a custom 500 page that will show up for users?
2) How can I test the response/error using non-.htaccess methods?

Yes, I have searched here on Server Fault.
Yes, I tried to Google it as well.
No, I haven't found anything on how to do a simple test. (Every time I found something causing a 500 response, it seemed to require me loading up lord-knows-what systems.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within your virtual host conf (or httpd.conf/apache2.conf) you can use the ErrorDocument directive, as follows:

`ErrorDocument 500 /errordocs/500error.php`

It's inadvisable to do too much in your 500 error page, as you could hit the same error condition that caused the 500 response in the first place!

Comment: Thanks for the response Steve.
I admit - I've been thinking much the same about problems repeating,
such as if PHP goes down, then using PHP in the error file is a liability.
So your suggestion would work fine for static - with little/no risk.
The reason for wanting to use PHP in the error doc is to send a different response - a 503 is much more preferable than a 500 as far as Google goes.

Comment: Further - does anyone have any ideas on how to "test" the 500 error?  I've looked around the Net, and not seen a single method for "testing" such an error. :(

Comment: @Clueless - "anyone have any ideas on how to "test" the 500 error?" `telnet localhost 80` + (Enter) + `HEAD /path/to/500/error/page HTTP/1.1` + (Enter) + `Host: yourhost.com` + (Enter) + (Enter)

Comment: @Clueless if PHP blows up to the point where it can't handle running a simple "custom error page" script you have bigger problems than your error page -- That Should Never Happen kind of problems. :-)

Comment: @voretaq7 - you could feasibly have a database failure which leads to the original 500 - and if your 500-handling php script attempts to read from the same database... well, you get the idea.

Comment: @Steve Mayne True, but there's no good reason I can think of for your 500 error page to read from a database (and if there's a good reason I didn't think of you can certainly check for that kind of failure and degrade gracefully -- you can also do so in your original script, obviating the need for the error page in the first place ;)

Comment: Well - I'll be using a CMS - and that permits customised error handling (with correct/alterable Respons codes.
But a 500 is Server based ... and I'm just not seeing any way for a normal user to alter it/customise it.
It looks like the only way so far is as per ...Steve... and altering the Conf - which will require the Host to make the changes in this case - and no gaurantee they will comply :(
I see tons of "custom 500" topics - but No One seems to verify it actually works, nor how they tested it (Good old Internet C&P :D).

Comment: ...danlefree... if I understand the telnet suggestion - that is basically the equivelenet of my browsing to the custom 500 error page.
If so - that isn'exactly what I'm after.  I'm after a sure fire way (without using htaccess) to create a 500 error on a lamp server using something like php ... so I can see if my custom 500 page shows up, or if the default one occurs.

Comment: @Clueless - just create a page with a PHP syntax error? <?php fail

Comment: That won't work - it generates a php error - not a server one.

Comment: Guess the only option is to alter the server setup for this scenario, then mess with htaccess to cause the fault - as it seems there isn't a way to generate server errors easily/sufficiently :(

Comment: Isn't a php error a 500 error if you have error reporting turned off?  What's your error reporting set to in your php.ini file?

Comment: I've turned it on/off : left it blank, used E_All and -E_All etc.
I've turn Display_Errors on/off as well.
The Only time I get a 500 is with Display off and Errors blank/-E_All.
And no custom page shows up, nor does the Default - just a blank white page.

And I've then gone through it all again without .htaccess being around - to ensure it isn't something in htaccess playing up.

Comment: Update : Okay - the host has the server set so the CHMod of 666 results in an Error - and I've managed to test the 500 response.
Indeed - my little php 500 Error page works fine (now giving a 503 response instead).

Still leaves the issue of generally testing such a response - really am surprised no simple method exists (Will re-attempt the various Error setting computations, and see if I can get it to flag that way now I know it works).